# Cannot Compile Jade " /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory "

Tags: ubuntu, pug

after installing I can't compile the file.
I use: `jade -w index.jade` but It's not working.
I'm using Ubuntu 64bit.
Here is my output from terminal:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you installed node(js)?

Comment: yes, i installed already. now i solve this problem by update nodejs, npm, and install jade --global